# Can you connect multiple analysis ports to single implementation?

Tags: system-verilog, verification, uvm

I have multiple environments and each one of them is responsible for certain portion of the coverage. Because of that I'm forced to write multiple implementation functions, which works, but it gets inconvenient with the scale. Is there a way to connect multiple analysis ports to same implementation as shown in picture?

[image: Picture Link]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, *but* only of the transactions are the same or share a common base class. An `imp` can only receive transactions parameterized to the same class.

It also matters if/how you need to track which `env` sends a coverage  transaction to your coverage component. You can

- use a field with a unique value in each transaction
- use different extended class types fore each env

Another option us using an array of `imps` like `analysis_fifo` and each array index connected to each `env`.

Answer (score -1):

The only way producer knows about the consumer is what we do in connect function. For analysis port, what the producer expects is the port handle and presence of .write implementation.
In our case here, we have try connecting same port implementation.
ahb_mon.ahb2scb.connect(ahb_apb_scoreboard.all2scb);
apb_mon.apb2scb.connect(ahb_apb_scoreboard.all2scb);